# What is happening in the below code it small part of my pom.xml?

Tags: maven, profiles

My Pom.xml file contains below code what does it means?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>inmemory</id>
        <properties>
            <env>inmemory</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cloudbees</id>
        <properties>
            <env>cloudbees</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: It declares two profiles: an in-memory profile and a cloudbees profile. Do you have a basic understanding of pom files? Have you read the docs?

Comment: @janos what is profiles and what graph of pom files?

Comment: I mistyped, I meant, if you have an understanding of pom files. Because you'll need it.

Comment: i know the basic understanding of pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means nothing in particular, it only declares two [build profiles](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html) each one of them set the value of the `env` property.

The meaning depends on how such declaration is used.

For example if in your `pom.xml` there is something like:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <built-for-environment>${env}</built-for-environment>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>inmemory</id>
        <properties>
            <env>inmemory</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cloudbees</id>
        <properties>
            <env>cloudbees</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and you run:

```
mvn clean install -Pinmemory
```

than in the generated `MANIFEST.MF` you can find the row:

```
built-for-environment: inmemory
```

So the meaning, in this example, is to add in the `MANIFEST.MF` an entry row with `built-for-environment:` followed by the name of the profile id.

You can answer yourself, finding the meaning for your project, by searching for `${env}` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

A Build profile is a set of configuration values which can be used to set or override default values of Maven build. Using a build profile, you can customize build for different environments such as Production v/s Development environment?

so here It declares two profiles: an in-memory profile and a cloudbees profile.

Answer (score 0):

Profilers a new feature of the POM 4.0 is the ability of a project to change settings depending on the environment where it is being built. A profile element contains both an optional activation (a profile trigger) and the set of changes to be made to the POM if that profile has been activated. For example, a project built for a test environment may point to a different database than that of the final deployment. Or dependencies may be pulled from different repositories based upon the JDK version used.

so here It declares two profiles: an in-memory profile and a cloudbees profile.